# 2018 WIT layout different from layout preview

Tags: tfs

We are currently testing out TFS2018 to upgrade from 2015. As there is no 2018 Process Editor it seems the 2017 version is the one to use. Without changing the WITs the format is radically different. Most noticeably the tabs in the WIT are no longer working and display totally differently by being sort of being expandable. The other part of that means the HTML entry field are all listed on the main WIT screen as opposed under the tabs or their replacement expandable sections but the other fields are there.

The 2017 editor shows them the way they were in 2015 but once in TFS 2018 they display differently. Any idea of what the issue is?

Comment: While I now know it is due to the 2018 upgrade it appears there is the ability to switch on or off the new layout. The problem is  I can't find the option on the screens suggested by the documentation. Do I need to change the WITs anyway to allow the ability to use the new or old format?

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2017 introduced a [new work item layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process/new-work-item-experience?view=tfs-2018), and TFS 2018 made it mandatory. You'll have to adapt to the new layout and adjust things accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that. It would have made more sense if the editor had both previews.